# How to programmatically access performance counters in c/c++ a-la-rdtsc?

Tags: c++, performance, intel, performancecounter

I often measure code snippets using rdtsc which gives me an idea of cycles taken by reading in the time stamp counter but I am aware that processors (in particular mine is an intel Xeon) have performance counters to measure branch misses and all other good stuff. How do I read that? Is it possible with similar code to rdtsc (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdtsc) ? Also, I am aware there is a product called perfmon which does this but I would like to do this myself in a simple programmatic way to also learn more. How can I get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/). It provides an API for doing this.

Comment: Thanks, this looks cool - if you ever have trouble with it (in my case im getting 0 num_counters and im on Xeon 5K series processor so im trying to diagnose what's wrong) where do you go to besides their site and man?